# Can not set cascading property while setting single property works fine

Tags: c#, .net

Following Code does not set the property.
It just does nothing and at debugging just jumps ahead, even with F11

```
job.TDataReference.CheckedOut = false;
```

job is of Type TJob
A class I build myself with the property:

```
public TDataReference TDataReference
{
    get
    {
        return new TDataReference(this.DataReference);
    }
    set { this.tDataReference = value; }
}
```

TDataReference is also a class I build myself with the property:

```
public bool CheckedOut
{
    get { return (dataRow[CHECKEDOUT].ToString() == "True"); }
    set { dataRow[CHECKEDOUT] = value.ToString(); }
}
```

and and the private member dataRow of Type DataRow

What is funny is that following code works fine and sets the property:

```
TDataReference dr = job.TDataReference;
dr.CheckedOut = false;
```

Who can explain that to me.

---

**Update**

---

Many thanks for your Answers!
I understand the problem. :)

tDataReference depends on the value in this.DataReference so earlyest time tDataReference can be set is when this.DataReference is known. How do you think about changing it to this:

```
private TDataReference tDataReference;

public TDataReference TDataReference
{
    get
    {
    if(tDataReference == null | tDataReference.Id != this.DataReference)
    {
        this.tDataReference = new TDataReference(this.DataReference);
    }        
    return this.tDataReference 
    }
    set { this.tDataReference = value; }
}
```

and wil setting the cascading Property work then???

Comment: Did you mean to create a new `TDataRefernece` every time it is retrieved? That defeats the point of having a setter. And what do you mean `does not set the property`? Assign a value? What is `tDataReference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your property getter creates new instance every time you call it. This code:

```
job.TDataReference.CheckedOut = false; // here you setting CheckedOut for the 1st instance of TDataReference
job.TDataReference.CheckedOut = false; // here you setting CheckedOut for the 2nd instance of TDataReference
```

is analogue of this pseudocode:

```
var tDataRef1 = new TDataReference(job.DataReference);
tDataRef1.CheckedOut = false;

var tDataRef2 = new TDataReference(job.DataReference);
tDataRef2.CheckedOut = false;
```

You shouldn't write property this way, this violates design guidelines. Consider the result of this condition:

```
job.TDataReference == job.TDataReference // false, ooops...
```

To avoid this situation, fix the property such a way:

```
public TDataReference TDataReference
{
    get
    {
        return tDataReference;
    }
    set { this.tDataReference = value; }
}
// field initialization is optional here, you can omit it 
// or make lazy initialization in getter like this: 
// return tDataReference ?? (tDataReference = new TDataReference(this.DataReference));
private TDataReference tDataReference = new TDataReference(this.DataReference);
```

Comment: You should update the *question*. Do not post the answer, which is a part of your question.

Comment: sry, I am new here and not yet familiar with the UI. I will try this